# is == null while getting xml file from internet

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following situation: I need to get xml file from the Internet and then get lyrics from this file. [Here's the url of this xml](http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist=Eminem&song=Lose%20Yourself). Here's the code, which I wrote and which should do it.

```
private static class NetworkLyricsDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist=Eminem&song=Lose%20Yourself");
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
                XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = factory.newPullParser();
                xmlPullParser.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF-8");
                boolean insideItem = false;
                int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();
                while (eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                        if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("lyric")){
                            insideItem = true;
                            Log.i(getClass().getName(), xmlPullParser.nextText());
                        }
                    }
                    eventType = xmlPullParser.next();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        private InputStream getInputStream(URL url){
            try {
                return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But when I run the app, I have the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: asus.example.com.player, PID: 14458
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.setInput(KXmlParser.java:1636)
        at asus.example.com.player.UploadLyricsActivity$NetworkLyricsDownload.doInBackground(UploadLyricsActivity.java:114)
        at asus.example.com.player.UploadLyricsActivity$NetworkLyricsDownload.doInBackground(UploadLyricsActivity.java:86)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I have permission in manifest file (    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
) but it still doesn't help. So, what's the matter and how can I solve it?

**UPD**

Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="asus.example.com.player"
    android:targetSandboxVersion="1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning,UnusedAttribute">
        <activity android:name=".SongLyricsActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".UploadLyricsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ListOfSongsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a previous exception

Comment: Your `getInputStream` explicitly returns null if there is a problem, and you don't check whether it returns null or not. Maybe you should let that exception be thrown and debug that. Catching it and trying to have your program just carry on regardless does not seem to work.

Comment: Try to add read and write permissions to your manifest and enabled it

Comment: Probably your getInputStream returns null

Comment: @RafałSokalski, yes, but why?

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii is there any IOException thrown ? Did you put whole stacktrace ?